# Flex-grow not working Tailwind React h-screen

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

So i have an component with child inside the div component, it works fine at first but when the component keep increasing, instead of pushing the the footer the component overlapping the footer component causing an error like this:
[image]

as you can see it stack infront of the footer and overlapping it....
here is my try:

```
<div className="m-2 flex-grow">
      <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row md:justify-between">
        <div className="flex">
          <div
            name=" grey window"
            className="h-[130px] w-[130px] bg-[#d9d9d9]"
          ></div>
          <div name="text" className="md :flex md:flex-col md:pt-0">
            <div className="ml-2 text-left text-[#e44] md:text-xl text-base">
              {props.props.sku_name}
            </div>
            <div className="md:text-l ml-2 text-left text-sm text-[#b4b4b4]">
              {`Plant: ${props.props.plant}`}
            </div>
            <div className="md:text-l ml-2 text-left text-sm text-[#b4b4b4]">
              {`SKU: ${props.props.sku}`}
            </div>{" "}
            <div className="md:text-l ml-2 text-left text-sm text-[#b4b4b4]">
              {`Status: ${props.props.status}`}
            </div>
            <div className="md:text-l ml-2 text-left text-sm text-[#b4b4b4]">
              {`Base Qty :${props.props.base_qty}, UOM: ${props.props.uom}`}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div name="Buttons">
          <div className="mt-2 flex gap-4 md:mt-0 md:flex-col">
            <div className="rounded-md shadow">
              <Button
                variant="outlined"
                size="medium"
                color="error"
                startIcon={<ContentCopyIcon />}
                className="inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent w-32 bg-indigo-600  text-base font-medium text-white hover:bg-indigo-700 "
              >
                Copy
              </Button>
            </div>
            <div className="rounded-md shadow">
              <Button
                variant="outlined"
                size="medium"
                startIcon={<ModeEditIcon />}
                color="warning"
                className="inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent w-32 bg-indigo-600  text-base font-medium text-white hover:bg-indigo-700"
              >
                Edit
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>{" "}
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>{" "}
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>{" "}
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>{" "}
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>{" "}
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>{" "}
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>{" "}
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>{" "}
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>{" "}
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>{" "}
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>{" "}
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>{" "}
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>{" "}
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>{" "}
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>{" "}
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>{" "}
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>{" "}
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
      </div>
      {/* <div className="bg-white">
        <Box sx={{ width: "100%", typography: "body1" }}>
          <TabContext
            TabIndicatorProps={{ style: { background: "#FF0000" } }}
            value={value}
            index={0}
            classes={{ root: useStyles.tab }}
          >
            <Box sx={{ borderColor: "divider", p: 0 }}>
              <TabList
                index={0}
                classes={{}}
                onChange={handleChange}
                variant="scrollable"
                scrollButtons="auto"
                aria-label="scrollable auto tabs example"
              >
                <Tab label="BOM" value="1" />
                <Tab label="Calculation" value="2" />
              </TabList>
            </Box>
            <TabPanel style={{ padding: 2 }} value="1">
              Calculation
              <div>
                <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
              </div>{" "}
              <div>
                <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
              </div>{" "}
              <div>
                <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
              </div>{" "}
              <div>
                <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
              </div>{" "}
              <div>
                <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
              </div>{" "}
              <div>
                <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
              </div>{" "}
              <div>
                <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
              </div>{" "}
              <div>
                <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
              </div>{" "}
              <div>
                <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
              </div>{" "}
              <div>
                <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
              </div>{" "}
              <div>
                <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
              </div>{" "}
              <div>
                <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
              </div>{" "}
              <div>
                <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
              </div>{" "}
              <div>
                <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
              </div>{" "}
              <div>
                <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
              </div>{" "}
              <div>
                <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
              </div>{" "}
              <div>
                <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p>dsajfkhjkfhkjasdhfkjahsdfkasjhdkfjashdkgdfgsfhdhh</p>
              </div>
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value="2" style={{ padding: 2 }}>
              Calculation
            </TabPanel>
          </TabContext>
        </Box>
      </div> */}
    </div>
```

and here is where i actually call the component to be used and display where there is data on it:

```
<div className=" m-2 p-2 mr-2 bg-white h-screen ">
      <div className="text-left pl-2 pb-4 font-bold text-3xl">
        <h2>Find Material</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="p-2 align-left">
        <form
          className="flex items-center"
          onSubmit={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            dataSKUList();
          }}
        >
          <Autocomplete
            isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
              option.value === value.value
            }
            style={{ width: "100%", color: "#ffffff" }}
            onChange={(event, newValue) => {
              handleSetSKU(newValue);
            }}
            id="grouped-demo"
            options={options.sort(
              (a, b) => -b.firstLetter.localeCompare(a.firstLetter)
            )}
            groupBy={(option) => option.firstLetter}
            getOptionLabel={(option) =>
              option.sku_name + `, code:(${option.sku})`
            }
            sx={{ width: 300 }}
            renderInput={(params) => {
              params.inputProps.onKeyDown = handleKeyDown;
              return <TextField {...params} label="Search by SKU" required />;
            }}
            renderGroup={(params) => (
              <ul key={params.key}>
                <li>
                  <GroupHeader>{params.group}</GroupHeader>
                  <GroupItems>{params.children}</GroupItems>
                </li>
              </ul>
            )}
          />
          <div>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              color="success"
              variant="contained"
              style={{
                marginLeft: 10,
                width: "100%",
                height: 54,
              }}
              startIcon={<ContentPasteSearchIcon />}
            >
              Search
            </Button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className="bg-white scrollbar-hide">
        {show ? (
          <div className="h-full">
            <CardCalculation props={dataSpec} />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
```

can someone pointing out where it potentially be the error and any help on how to fix it?...
i think it will the `h-screen` that causing the problem....

Comment: Hi , Your footer is missing in the code

Comment: I have added the answer, let me know if you have further requirements based on the link below

Answer (score 1):

Use `flex-1` instead of `flex-grow`

Try [Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/ehESv4O6tb)

I have added the footer, and now you dont see any overflow.

Comment: the footer is on other file... i made it into the layout component, actually it doesnt works.. but may be u wanna see the whole component which i use the footer and call the child component?.... @KrishnaAcharya

Comment: I can't see your footer, could you point me at it